# Populating Cells Based on Dropdowns in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Alright. I'm setting up a character sheet for a D&D esque combat system for something. I have a chart with two columns; A and B. We'll call this Sheet1. Column A is trait names, column B is their corresponding descriptions.

On a separate sheet, Sheet2, I have a data validation drop down in column B corresponding to the trait names in column A on Sheet1. I need Sheet2, column C to auto populate with the trait description from Sheet1 column B corresponding to the selected trait from the drop down.

I have googled this with every possible change of phrasing I can think of and I cannot find a solution. If I could get Google sheets to understand Python I'd be golden and have this done already, but sadly I cannot. Can anyone help? I thought about just daisy chaining `=(IF)`'s but theres going to be about 50 different traits to choose from and that's just not efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH that did it, had to modify cell ranges to fit the need but that did the trick. Thank you thank you thank you